# Dynamically create Prometheus gauge names

Tags: javascript, node.js, prometheus

I am using [prom-client](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client) in my node app to send stats to our prometheus instance. I am firing off a set of requests to determine if the app is up or not. With that, I want to dynamically set the name of the gauge depending on what app is being pinged.

```
apps.map(app => {
  request(app.url, (error, response, body) => {
    let name = app.name
    const gauge = new client.Gauge({
      name: `${app.name}`,
      help: `${app.name}`,
      register,
    })
    if (error) {
      console.log(`${app.name} ERROR!`, error)
      gauge.set(0)
    }
    if (response && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(`${app.name} is up!`, response.statusCode)
      gauge.set(0)
    }
    gateway.pushAdd({ jobName: 'app_up_down', register })
  })
})
```

Setting the gauge name to `${app.name}` is throwing an Invalid Name error. The only way I could get it to stop throwing that error was to hardcode the name which doesn't work for me. Does anyone know if there is a way to dynamically set this, or is this an issue with the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like blackbox monitoring, for which the [blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) is probably a better tool.

The particular error you're getting is likely as the name contains invalid characters, a label would be a better choice. In addition this is [not a good use of the pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/).

Comment: I understand, but our infrastructure is build on Kubernetes which has prometheus. I know it's not a good use of the pushgateway, however our apps are behind a firewall and the metrics cannot be scraped. Pushing to the pushgateway is our only option. 

Can you provide a little more insight for the invalid characters? What is allowed/what isn't? This is my first time using prometheus and all that is in the strings are letters A-Z

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/  Run the Prometheus behind the firewall.